# get copy of div data in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

HTML Part:-

```
<form id="inquiryform" method="" />
    <h2>INQUIRY FORM</h2>
    <div class="margin5">
        <div class="floatleft width100"><span class="borderbottom">Party Name</span> </div>
        <div class="floatleft"><input type="text" name="PartyName" size="60"/></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</form>
<div> <input type="button" id="submitform" value="Send Mail"/></div>
```

Jquery :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitform').click(function(){
        var data = 'message='+$('#inquiryform').html();
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

When I click on my send mail button then it will OK html part which I want to get but when I entered something in textbox then `data` variable always be empty.
I want to like that whatever I write in text-box that must be a part of the `data` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this lines before '`var data=...`' line:

```
$('#inquiryform :text').attr('value',function(){
    return $(this).val();
});
```

This will add '`value`' attribute on all `input[type="text"]` tags.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ny5RH/)

Answer (score 1):

The text entered in the `<input>` doesn't show in the `.html()` result because it doesn't change the DOM. It just affects the `value` *property* (not the *attribute*) of the element.

If you want to retrieve its value you should use `$("[name=PartyName]").val()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the data of every element of the form (not the html, just data) use [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)